# Rename items in PostgreSQL or any SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, zoho

I am working with a program named zoho reports and trying to change names of objects in the file I uploaded. ZOHO cannot rename the example. I want to use SQL, preferably Postgres.

`phonenumber`:

```
1. 5203123333
2. 8323125547
3. 6025456564
4. 43654xxx3
```

I want them to display as:

```
1. TUCSON,AZ
2. Houston,TX
3. Chandler,AZ
4. WHATEVER
```

I have used this:

```
SELECT "TO", replace("TO",
    '4802xxx82', 'Chandler'), replace("TO",
    '832xxxx84', 'Houston, TX'), FROM "Craiglist-December Calls"
```

Works but returns a new column. I need only one new column.

Then I tried an `IF` condition, but error after I try more then three renames.

```
if("To"='83xxxx284','Houston TX',if("To"='818xxxx6','Santa Clarita CA','0'))
```

Trying to replace about 8 numbers with names, so I can graph them by name not number.
Is there a way to rename all these number in the same column with Postgres?

Comment: Ain't no such thing as "Postgre". [The short name of PostgreSQL is Postgres.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you want *"the same column"*, meaning the same column *name*. So use a [column alias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). And use a ["simple" `CASE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
SELECT CASE "TO"            -- "simple" CASE
          WHEN '4802xxx82' THEN 'Chandler'
          WHEN '832xxxx84' THEN 'Houston, TX'
          WHEN ...          -- 6 more ...
          ELSE "TO"
       END AS "TO"          -- column alias (output column name)
FROM   "Craiglist-December Calls";
```

Your column names are not chosen wisely. Never use keywords as identifiers. If you double-quote identifiers to allow illegal names, you need to double-quote the now case-sensitive!) name for the rest of its life. <strike>`"To"`</strike> is *not* a valid reference to `"TO"`.

Start with the [manual about identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Thank you, Works inside of ZOHO reports query!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to have second table with "translations". First column (pattern) like `83____284` and second column (display) - the new name `Houston TX`. Then select like this:

```
SELECT t2.display FROM orig_table t1, translate_table t2 WHERE t1.phonenumber LIKE t2.pattern
```

PS: PostgreSQL is abbreviation of "Postgres SQL" (with S).

Answer (score 1):

probably the best way to do this is to greate a table with the phone numbers and locations.
I'm going to use `text` columns because I'm targeting postgresql, for other databases vharchar() columns or apropriate width would probably be a better choice.

```
creare table phnne_directory (phone text primary key, location text);
insert into phnne_directory values ('5203123333','TUCSON,AZ'),
    ('8323125547','Houston,TX')
    ('6025456564','Chandler,A')'
    ('43654xxx3','WHATEVER');

SELECT C."TO", coalesce(p.location,'unknown')
    FROM "Craiglist-December Calls" as c
    JOIN phnne_directory as p on p.phone = c.to;
```

this way you keep the data out of the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the following:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN "TO" = '4802xxx82' THEN 'Chandler'
     WHEN "TO" = '832xxxx84' THEN 'Houston, TX'
     ELSE "TO"
  END AS "TO"
FROM "Craiglist-December Calls"
```

You may add other conditions within CASE statement as well, all results will appear in one column.
Please find more about `CASE` statment in Postgre **[here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html)**